# Why do one need hostname if it has FQDN?

Tags: dns, hostname, resolv.conf

One would set up his hostname in `/etc/hostname`.
I wonder why one might need to use FQDN if he has his DNS server properly configured?

Say, for example, one has following configuration of bind that servers his FQDN too.

```
$ORIGIN department.domain.

@ IN SOA department.domain. dnsmaster (
  1
  604800
  86400
  2419200
  604800)

  IN NS department.domain.
  IN NS ns.department.domain.

department.domain.    IN A 192.168.0.7
ns.department.domain. IN A 192.168.0.8
employee007.department.domain. IN A 192.168.12.2
```

Now configuration of client machine:

Have in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
search department.domain.
nameserver 192.168.0.8
```

I see that it is possible to resolve FQDN of this host just issuing

```
dig @192.168.0.8 employee007.department.domain
```

**Why one might need to have /etc/hostname filled with hostname
or string in /etc/hosts like this:**

```
127.0.1.1 employee007.department.domain. employee007
```

**If DNS server alone solves the problem?** One might consider dropping out /etc/hostname and unneeded stuff in /etc/hosts altogether if gets a reasonable rationale. Thanks.

Comment: You mean there are many disadvantages and complications of running DNS server? I will glad if write an answer clarifying your point.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/hostname` is mainly used to set the hostname at bootup. Now you also could accept the hostname the DNS server pushes out. That's OK in small environments where you can keep records of each single client.
In a big network environment, where you have a lot of different subnets and clients, you normally want the client to push his hostname to the DNS server. Otherwise an admin would have to adopt the DNS entries every time the client gets a new IP address.

`/etc/hosts` is nowadays mainly used for the localhost lookups which normally also includes the real hostname. As muru already outlined, it might be that your DNS lookup is broken or incorrect and a service or configuration that relies on a DNS lookup of the hostname would fail.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "Otherwise an admin would have to adopt the DNS entries every time the client gets a new IP address.".  A bit vague for me. Thanks.

Comment: When you have static DNS entries like `myhost` resolves to `192.168.0.12`, you also have to make sure that `192.168.0.12` is assigned to `myhost`. When one now moves his computer to another building where a different subnet is assigned from DHCP, like `192.168.1.0/24`, the computer will get e.g. `192.168.1.12` as address but the DNS entry would still resolve to `192.168.0.12`.

Comment: And what does mean " you normally want the client to push his hostname to the DNS server"? Isn't it about using dynamic updates to bind?

Comment: Yes, dynamic DNS updates. Announced by the client.

Comment: Could you give some insight why kernel needs hostname? Just curious.